# tensorflow tf.edit_distance explanation required?

Tags: python, tensorflow

How does tensorflow `tf.edit_distance` function works?
How it compares string stored in two different sparse matrix equivalent of 2d or 3d dense matrix.

Example given on tensorflow web page https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/edit_distance is not so obvious. Please provide explanation using some other examples.

Also this example is not clear.

```
#'hypothesis' is a tensor of shape [2, 1] with variable-length values:
#(0,0) = ["a"] and (1,0) = ["b"]

hypothesis = tf.SparseTensor([[0, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0]],["a", "b"],(2, 1, 1))

#'truth' is a tensor of shape `[2, 2]` with variable-length values:
#(0,0) = [], (0,1) = ["a"], (1,0) = ["b", "c"],(1,1) = ["a"]

truth = tf.SparseTensor([[0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 1],[1, 1, 0]],["a", "b", 
"c", "a"],(2, 2, 2))

normalize = True

#'output' is a tensor of shape [2, 2] with edit distances normalized by 
#'truth' lengths.

output ==> [[inf, 1.0],[0.5, 1.0]],

(0,0): no truth, (0,1): no hypothesis, (1,0): addition, (1,1): no hypothesis
```

How output is of dimension [2,2]?

What normalization is doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hypothesis in dense form looks like this

```
[[['a']],
 [['b']]] # (2, 1, 1)
```

truth is this

```
[[[],['a']],
 [['b', 'c'], ['a']]] # (2, 2, 2)
```

We are trying to find the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between hypothesis and truth value.
So, here is what is happening:

at (0,0,0) - how far is ['a'] in hypothesis from [] - no truth in that position so can't calculate distance

at (0,0,1) - since there is nothing in that position at hypothesis we return 1. Unlike the case above, the distance is 1 because in theory the hypothesis can be made same as truth by inserting one character (See Levenshtein distance calculations)

at (1,0,0) - how far is ['b'] in hyp from ['b', 'c'] in truth. This is again 1, since we can insert a character to make hyp same as truth. But, we selected to normalize the output distance. So we divide by length of truth segment, which is 2. So you get 0.5

at (1,0,1) - how far is [] in hyp from ['a'], since there is nothing in that position at hyp, we return 1

Output is (2,2) because rank of hyp and truth is 3. The function returns tensor with rank (rank-1)

It helps by imagining what we are trying to do here. You have 2 sequences in hypothesis and 2 sequences in the truth. So your output score will be such that you get scores for each position in each sequence.

Here is an example where we try to match 4 hypotheses to a truth value. I think you have to do this for each truth sequence for the use case that you describe in your comment - let me know if you find something more efficient :-)

```
import tensorflow as tf

hypothesis = tf.SparseTensor(
            [[0, 0, 0],
             [1, 0, 0],
             [2, 0, 0],
             [3, 0, 0]],
             ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
            (4, 1, 1))

truth = tf.SparseTensor([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]], ["b", "c", "a"], (1,2,2))
num_hyp = 4
truth = tf.sparse_concat(0, [truth] * num_hyp)

d = tf.edit_distance(hypothesis, truth)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(d))
```

Output:

```
[[1.  1. ]
 [0.5 1. ]
 [0.5 1. ]
 [1.  1. ]]
```

Comment: Thanks @dgumo for your answer. So I see that last dimension is always assumed to represent sequence, that is why function returns tensor with rank less than original rank. Also suppose if I have 2 sequences representing truth and I want to find edit distance from the sequences generated from RNN (hypotheses) say 40 sequences. Then how to represent truth and hypotheses so that I get 80 distances (40 hypo compared to 1st truth seq and then 40 hypo compared to 2nd truth seq)?

Comment: Updated answer to accommodate your case above.